How do I set the random seed for Chroma DB?
I'm experimenting with different embedding models. Chroma seems to return docs with a heuristic. I want to fix that for my experiments.
How do I set the random seed for Chroma to use?
E.g., when I query 10 docs, if I change the search_ef parameter, and change it back again to its original value, I get different results than in the first time.
collection = chroma_client.get_collection(name="...")
collection.modify(metadata={"hnsw:search_ef": 20})
embedded_question = embeddings.embed_query(question)
query_results = collection.query(query_embeddings=[embedded_question], n_results=10)

